# REST API or java library to get the release date of a Java library

Tags: java, rest

REST API to get release date of a Java library once the Group ID, Artifact ID and the Version of a particular library is given.

Comment: The release date? You're not guaranteed that that is even mentioned in the sub poms. I guess you might have to check the last modified date of either the pom itself (likely to be wrong), or check the contents of the jar-files yourself, getting e.g the manifest date from there. Might be someone else knows another solution, though..

Comment: Why do you think you need to do that?

Comment: Actually I am writing a program that reads a pom file, get all the dependency details and I have to tell the date they have been released

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is http://search.maven.org/ has a rest API. Support only the libraries in the Maven central. Timestamp field (in milliseconds) gives the answer.

Comment: The issue is that this API has subpar documentation. Moreover, I am unsure about rate limiting or issues related to that, especially if one would need to query hundreds of thousands or more libraries.